# How do I declare static variables before constructors, and how do I refer to a class in its body?

Tags: python, oop, class

I'm used to declare static fields/variables in a class before the constructor(s). When doing so in Python it results in an error.

Here's an example class:

```
class StringCompare:

    methods = OrderedDict()
    # ERROR!:
    #methods['equals'] = equals
    #methods['ends with'] = endswith
    #methods['starts with'] = startswith
    #methods['contains'] = contains

    @staticmethod
    def equals(a, b):
        return a == b

    @staticmethod
    def contains(a, b):
        return a.find(b) != -1

    @staticmethod
    def startswith(a, b):
        return a.startswith(b)

    @staticmethod
    def endswith(a, b):
        return a.endswith(b)

    methods['equals'] = equals
    methods['ends with'] = endswith
    methods['starts with'] = startswith
    methods['contains'] = contains
```

Are there any more elegant ways (aside from placing all statements directly after the whole class prefixing each accessed var with `StringCompare.`)?

What's the best practice here?

---

A more complex case would be when trying to call a constructor from within the same class:

```
class Type(InlineFragment):

    # primitive types get None as package name
    def __init__(self, packageName, name, genericType=None):

        ...

    def ...

    primitive = {
        'Character': Type(None, 'char'),
        'Byte'     : Type(None, 'byte'),
        'Short'    : Type(None, 'short'),
        'Integer'  : Type(None, 'int'),
        'Long'     : Type(None, 'long'),
        'Boolean'  : Type(None, 'boolean'),
        'Float'    : Type(None, 'float'),
        'Double'   : Type(None, 'double'),
    }
```

This results in an error:

```
\jpa_export_fragments.py", line 361, in Type
    'Character'    : Type(None, 'char'),
NameError: name 'Type' is not defined
```

This should work, but I can only solve this by putting this code outside the class.

Comment: While I tried to supply useful examples, the answer is really "Python is different. Learn its unique style." In Python, not everything has to be in a class. `primatives` should probably be a module-level variable following the definition of `Type`.

Answer (score 3):

In general, the solution is to use [class decorators](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3129/). For your examples, you probably want to combine them with class methods:

```
def apply_method(attr):
    def apply_to(cls):
        setattr(cls, attr, getattr(cls, '_' + attr)())
        return cls
    return apply_to

@apply_method('primative')
class Type(object):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def _primative(cls):
        return {
    'Character': cls(None, 'char'),
    'Byte'     : cls(None, 'byte'),
    'Short'    : cls(None, 'short'),
    'Integer'  : cls(None, 'int'),
    'Long'     : cls(None, 'long'),
    'Boolean'  : cls(None, 'boolean'),
    'Float'    : cls(None, 'float'),
    'Double'   : cls(None, 'double'),
        }
```

Your first example looks very un-Pythonic, so I hesitate to suggest a decorator for that. Instead, perhaps you want a `str`ing subclass?

```
class StringCompare(str):
    # none of these are any different from the normal string operations
    # you would really only override ones that are different.

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return super(StringCompare, self).__eq__(other)

    def __contains__(self, other):
        return self.find(other) != -1

    def startswith(self, other):
        return super(StringCompare, self).startswith(other)

    def endswith(self, other):
        return super(StringCompare, self).endswith(other)


print StringCompare('boogaloo').startswith('boo') # True
```